# Design decision - What is the use/advantage of separate RandomNumberGeneratorHolder class in Math.java?

Tags: java, java-8, design-decisions

So I was going through the `Math.java` source code and I found that there is a holder class created to hold the [`randomNumberGenerator`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#l745) static variable. Here is the relevant piece of code.

```
public final class Math {
 // other methods.
 public static double random() {
   return RandomNumberGeneratorHolder.randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble();
 }

 private static final class RandomNumberGeneratorHolder {
   static final Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
 }
}
```

IMO, We could have simply declared the `randomNumberGenerator` as `private static final` inside the `Math` class itself.

My question is, Is there any advantage of creating a separate holder class for this? Or it is just a personal preference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an example of the [initialisation-on-demand holder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom). When the `Math` class is loaded by the JVM, the `Random` instance will not be constructed immediately. Instead that will only happen when the `random()` method is called, at which point the `RandomNumberGenreatorHolder` class will be loaded, and the `Random` singleton object constructed.

Essentially the code is ensuring that the `Random` singleton is created lazily.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense. :)

Answer (score 4):

They are both `lazy`, but one is `lazier` (singleton pattern that is). Having a `private static` field would mean that when the class holding that field is initialized, that field is initialized also. So if you need to call a method on that class, but *you don't need that singleton*, it will still get initialized.

On the other hand, having a nested class will prevent that, and it will be initialized when actually used.

To be exact, this is very rarely a case where this would matter and the jdk-itself is most probably one of the very very few examples.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a lazy-initialized singleton that is implemented using nested classes.

The "holder" gets initialized the first time that `random()` is called.  The first call triggers the execution of the static initialization of the `RandomNumberGeneratorHolder` class.

(It is worthwhile doing this lazily.  Initializing a random generator without supplying a seed entails going to the OS to get some "entropy" to seed the generator.  That is a relatively expensive operation.  You don't want the JVM incurring that cost that if `random()` is not going to be called.)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019306/regarding-static-holder-singleton-pattern) of this post, the purpose of the holder pattern is to get a single instance created for that class, invocation on demand (lazy loading) and also being thread-safe. It is the best option when you want to develop the Singleton pattern.