# Single static field in Java class

Tags: java, multithreading, static, synchronized

There is a class RedisLogger.java which used to deal with logger with redis. In RedisLogger.java, I declared a static JedisPool field `jedisPool` using this code:

```
private static JedisPool jedisPool;
```

Cause JedisPool is thread-safe calss, I want to instantiate `jedisPool` only once in my application by using the following code:

```
public static JedisPool getJedisPool() {
    if(jedisPool == null) {
        synchronized (JedisPool.class) {
            if(jedisPool == null) {
                jedisPool = new JedisPool();
            }
        }
    }
    return jedisPool;
}
```

I used this code to test it.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        executor.execute(()->{
            System.out.println(RedisLogger.getJedisPool());
        });
    }
```

It seems works well from output :

```
redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool@3d11fc5d
redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool@3d11fc5d
redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool@3d11fc5d
redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool@3d11fc5d
redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool@3d11fc5d
redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool@3d11fc5d
redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool@3d11fc5d
redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool@3d11fc5d
redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool@3d11fc5d
redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool@3d11fc5d
redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool@3d11fc5d
redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool@3d11fc5d
redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool@3d11fc5d
....
```

But can it really achieve my expectations?
Becasue there are many places like this in my application. for example.

```
private static Cluster getCluster() {
    if(cluster == null) {
        synchronized (Cluster.class) {
            if(cluster == null) {
                Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
                for (int i = 0; i < MSConfig.SRCDOC_CASSANDRA_ADDRS().length; i++) {
                    builder.addContactPoint(MSConfig.SRCDOC_CASSANDRA_ADDRS()[i])
                            .withPort(MSConfig.SRCDOC_CASSANDRA_PORT()[i]);
                }
                cluster = builder.withCredentials(MSConfig.SRCDOC_CASSANDRA_USERNMAE(), MSConfig.SRCDOC_CASSANDRA_PASSWORD())
                        .withProtocolVersion(ProtocolVersion.V4)
                        .withPoolingOptions(getPoolingOptions())
                        .withSocketOptions(getSocketOptions())
                        .withRetryPolicy(getRetryPolicy())
                        .withQueryOptions(getQueryOptions())
                        .build();
            }
        }
    }
    return cluster;
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: *But can it really achieve my expectations*. It should. Why shouldn't it? Do you see inconsistencies? We don't know your code, so we can't tell by looking at your last snippet if it will work. We would need the whole picture, but that would burst the frame of this question

Answer (score 1):

The only addition I think of is to drop that `synchronized` initialization and just directly go with the [*static-holder-pattern*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019306/regarding-static-holder-singleton-pattern). From the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24018148/5515060):

> The JVM **defers initializing the InstanceHolder class until it is actually used**, and because the Singleton is initialized with a static initializer, **no additional synchronization** is needed.

This can be used in your code like this:

```
public class RedisLogger{
     public static JedisPool getJedisPool(){
         return JedisPoolHolder.INSTANCE;
     }

     private static final class JedisPoolHolder{
         private static final JedisPool INSTANCE = new JedisPool();
     }

     // the rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is called "double checked locking". If you search this on Stackoverflow or Google you will find many explanations why it **does not work properly in Java**.

The alternatives are:

1. If it is very very likely that you will use this object when its holding class was loaded, then just initialize it directly and make the field final.
2. Declare the field `volatile`.
3. Use a holding class, i.e., have a private inner class that holds the field, which is then made `final`.

See also these questions:

- [Double Checked Locking in Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093735/double-checked-locking-in-singleton)
- [Java double checked locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625118/java-double-checked-locking)
- [Why is volatile used in this example of double checked locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855700/why-is-volatile-used-in-this-example-of-double-checked-locking)

Comment: I know，double checked  is used to Singleton pattern. But I want use it to a field.

Comment: The code you currently have can leak an uninitialized instance of `JedisPool`. This has nothing to do with singletons.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly assign a value to variable and declare it `final static` in your case.

Comment: `static` is the keyword that makes something a singelton. `final` only ansures, that the value of the variable can't be changed. Therefore, your answer as it stands is wrong

Comment: Right, it's not necessarily about singletons but in this context final would be nice because we don't want to modify the value, so since it will be assigned during declaration, it can be final. Edited my answer though.

Comment: But you will still need `static`

Comment: Little misunderstanding. I meant adding final to the modifiers, not replacing them with final. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Since it's a pool , I suppose it will be modified sometime... i don't think `final` is right here

Comment: I'm trying to used final field, but it can't because RedisLoggerl.java is util class. and  there is a static function '                   public static void execute(CallWithJedis caller) {
  try(Jedis jedis = getJedisPool().getResource()){
   caller.call(jedis);
  }
 }'  to uesd it.