# Synchronized singleton in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, synchronized

I am new to Kotlin. Still learning basic syntax.
I've heard about companion objects similar to static in Java. But don't know how to create synchronized singleton in Kotlin.

Comment: What do you mean by synchronized singleton?
Something like this in Java:

class Foo {

private static Foo instance;

public static synchronized Foo getInstance(){
   if (instance == null){instance=new Foo();}
   return instance;
}
}

Comment: @fgasparini.. Yes.

Answer (score 12):

Just use

```
object Singleton {
    // any members you need
}
```

It's already synchronized properly:

> [Object declaration's initialization is thread-safe.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations)

Note that this doesn't guarantee *calls* on it thread-safe, but that's just as in Java.

Comment: The OP seems to want his singleton to be lazy.  This one is not.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike Actually it is; it will be initialized when its class is loaded, and this only happens when it's first accessed.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike This applies in Java as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019306/regarding-static-holder-singleton-pattern

Comment: Exactly.  When the class is loaded, the first time the class is named.  That is not lazy in the sense that the OP seemed to want.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike Do you mean that Java code can have other `static` members which can be accessed without calling `getInstance()`? In Kotlin this corresponds simply to putting them on another `object` (including a nested one).

Comment: Does't work when the singleton needs an argument, like in Real Life.

Answer (score 2):

There are also other ways, but those two are the most simple ones to generate a singleton class

Method 1- Kotlin Way

```
object SingletonObj {
    init {
        // do your initialization stuff
    }
}
```

Method 2- Double Null Check Way in Kotlin

```
class SingletonObj {
    private constructor(context: Context)

    companion object {
        @Volatile private var mInstance: SingletonObj? = null

        public  fun get(context: Context): SingletonObj =
            mInstance ?: synchronized(this) {
                val newInstance = mInstance ?: SingletonObj(context).also { mInstance = it }
                newInstance
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: now `synchronized ` deprecated, is there any replacement for it?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/synchronized.html @RomanVasilyev

Answer (score 2):

**Thread-safe and lazy:**

```
class Singleton private constructor() {
    companion object {
        val instance: Singleton by lazy { Singleton() }
    }
}
```

Double null check already implemented inside `by lazy`.

Answer (score 1):

I think, little bit more research, and i found it . Here is how to do it . Please correct me if it can be done in better way.

```
companion object {
@Volatile private var INSTANCE: Singleton ? = null
 fun  getInstance(): Singleton {
         if(INSTANCE == null){
             synchronized(this) {
                 INSTANCE = Singleton()
             }
         }
         return INSTANCE!!
   }
}
```

Comment: @fgasparini , Request you to suggest if there is any better way .

Comment: That absolutely will not work.  You need a second null check inside the synchronized block.   ... and you might want to look at https://portabledroid.wordpress.com/2018/08/09/fast-locking-in-android-with-kotlin/

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike... can you please edit or post the corrected code

Comment: Double checked locking has been proven to not work years ago.  Kotlin runs on the JVM.  Doesn't work for Java, either.  Singleton is a discredited pattern.