# Kafka Admin Client in Multi Threading

Tags: apache-kafka

I have Kafka client with the following code,

```
private AdminClient getKafkaClient() {
        final Map<String, Object> configs = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "server-ip");
        return AdminClient.create(configs);
    }
```

This method invoked by multiple thread, and creates many admin client. So i wanted to keep in one instance and make use of it.

I've read an article for Singleton using Holder class with the below url,

[Regarding static holder singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019306/regarding-static-holder-singleton-pattern)

Looks good to me, when i tried to implement issue setting config and can't create instance. Can any one suggest me best idea in my problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Singleton would work fine. And you don't need a concurrent Hashmap. Please show your actual stacktrace

Comment: Alternatively, use a higher level framework like Spring Kafka or Akka Streams which can inject single instances for you

Comment: The below config works and managed to get running. Thank you @cricket_007

Answer (score 1):

The following looks good?? I made it to work.

```
public class KafkaAdminManager {

    private ConnectionConfig connectionConfig;
    private static final Map<String, Object> configs =  new HashMap<>();

    public KafkaAdminManager(ConnectionConfig connectionConfig) {
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, connectionConfig.getBootstrapServers());
        this.connectionConfig = connectionConfig;
    }

    private static class InstanceHolder {
        public static AdminClient instance = AdminClient.create(configs);
    }

    private KafkaAdminManager(){}

    public static AdminClient getInstance() {
        return InstanceHolder.instance;
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need two classes, but looks fine

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback.