# Simple timed based cache accessed by multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have data that i want to cache for set period of time, this data is accessed by multiple threads.

I have created simple cache mechanism for it:

```
public class ExpirationCache<T> {
    private final Supplier<T> computable;
    private final long validTime;
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private LocalDate lastAccess;
    private Future<T> data;

    public ExpirationCache(Supplier<T> computable, long validTime) {
        this.computable = computable;
        this.validTime = validTime;
    }

public boolean hasExpired() {
    if( lastAccess == null ){
        return true;
    }
    return LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(lastAccess.plus(validTime, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
}


    public T getData() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            if (hasExpired()) {
                FutureTask<T> ft = new FutureTask<T>(computable::get);
                try {
                    lock.lock();
                    if (hasExpired()) {
                        data.cancel(true);
                        data = ft;
                    }
                } finally {
                    lastAccess = LocalDate.now();
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
            try {
                return data.get();
            } catch (CancellationException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is about 'data' and 'lastAccess' variables, since i am making compound execution and not locking them on every access.

Could there be scenario

1. when first call to `hasExpired` results into false, but millisecond after, another thread calls the `getData` method `hasExpired` results into true, goes into sync block and change the `data` varaible refference and thus the first thread  results into undefinned behavior?
2. does locking prevents instruction reorganization? Or could i set new value for `data` and `lastAccess` in one thread since `hasExpired` was true, but the second thread invoked right would see new value for `lastAccess` but old value for data?

If some of the points are correct, what is the correct way to fix it? Do i need  make lastAccess or data AtomicRefferences? Every scenario which could lead to unwanted behavior includes `haxExpired` call, however locking it with lock would basicly made this class synchronous.

On top of that, given the scenario when calculation of data takes longer than `validTime`, before setting refference of `data` to new `Future` i cancel the operation, does this mean my `computable` variable has to listen fo `interrupted` flag to proper exit the computation ?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Note: `LocalDate` contains only date (day, month, year), but not time (hour, minute, second, millisecond), so `hasExpired` may not work like you would expect it to.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek ah yes should be LocalDateTime my bad.

Comment: Also, I may be wrong on this one, but the `FutureTask` does not seem like it would execute on the background, if you don't submit it to an executor.

Comment: @Johnyb No, not `LocalDateTime`. Never call `LocalDateTime.now`. That class lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So that class cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. For a moment, use `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime` (or `OffsetDateTime`, mainly for SQL in JDBC).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the well-established pattern used for thread safe singletons:

```
public class Singleton {

    private static volatile Singleton instance = null;

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized(Singleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

So in your case it would be:

```
public class ExpirationCache<T> {

    ... volatile variables

    public T getData() throws InterruptedException {
        if (data == null || isExpired()) {
            synchronized(lock) {
                if (data == null || isExpired()) {
                    data = computable.get();
                    lastAccess = Instant.now();
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

> 1. change the data varaible refference and thus the first thread results into undefinned behavior?

It would either return data that was still valid at the time of the request, or the refreshed data. That should not be a problem with cacheable data.

> 2. does locking prevents instruction reorganization?

I would suggest adding `volatile` keyword to all variables you don't want to get reorganized.

Comment: I thought an enum was the the well-established pattern used for thread safe singletons.

Comment: An enum is doing the same thing under the hood. (And also does not support inheritance)

Comment: This is not what an enum does under the hood.  This is not a well known pattern.  It isn't even a particularly good pattern.  OP: correct pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019306/regarding-static-holder-singleton-pattern

Comment: @markspace https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Lazy_initialization . Any reason, why it shouldn't be good? Do you know other simple, thread safe implementation for lazily initialized singleton? And if yes, why is it better than this one?

Comment: I don't care.  That's double checked locking, which is different from the well known Java pattern I linked to.